# Do you still use the .Net Configuration tool to give Visual Studio 2008 SP1 access permissions to code on a network drive? If so where is it?

Tags: .net, security, configuration

I can't seem to find the old mscorcfg.msc snap in to give .net permission to access a shared network drive. I've downloaded the Windows SDK 2008 which superseded .NET 2.0 SDK (where it used to be) but can't find it.

Does anyone know if it has been deprecated? Is there a new way to give .Net permissions to a shared network drive?

Comment: Sorry i should mention im running on Windows 2008

Answer (score 1):

You mention .Net 2.0 briefly, but it's not clear if that's what your targeting.  .Net 3.5 sp1 no longer requires special permissions to run from a network share.  .Net 2.0 through .Net 3.5 (no sp) do require such permissions.

Comment: Im running 3.5 (SP1) under visual studio 2008. If i try create an MVC project on a network share i get "This project location is not trusted" and if i run it i get "Failed to start monitoring changes to 'Z:\Code\Test\MvcApplication2\MvcApplication2'.

Comment: Okay.  That's an asp.net trusted/untrusted thing that you fix in IIS.  It's not the same as the code access security system introduced in .net 2.0.

Comment: Do you know where i go to fix that. Im running in the asp.net development server. Maybe i need to launch in IIS rather?

Comment: Sorry, don't know IIS that well.